# Finding growth percentage needed to hit a quota goal. Excel

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, formula

Things I know:

- Need to make $165,000 by the end of December to break even.
- Made $48,000 so far this year (Jan-Apr).
- Made $12,500 in April.

How would I figure out what my consistent growth would need to be to hit my break even point?

Doing a guess and check method I came up with 11.060176%. This means

- May = $13,882.52
- June = $15,417.95
- July = $17,123.21
- August = $19,017.06
- September = $21,120.38
- October = $23,456.34
- November = $26,050.65
- December = $28,931.89

I know the answer for this specific scenario is 11.060176% growth month over month, but that was with a lot of guess and check. How would you do this in a formulaic way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a math question. Perhaps a different forum?

Answer (score 0):

Place the jan-march value in **A1** and the april value in **A2**.

Place a guess growth rate in **C1** *(say 1.15)*.  In **A3** enter:

```
=A2 * $C$1
```

and copy downwards.  In **A11** enter:

```
=SUM(A1:A10)
```

[image]

Now we bring up Solver and tell it to adjust **C1** to drive **A11** to the goal of $165,000:

[image]

This yields 1.00977358283576

[image]

**NOTE:**

The growth rate is applied using the April amount as the base.

**EDIT#1**

I re-ran the model with **A1** reduced to $35,500 so that the sum of **A1** and **A2** is the required $48,000.  The new Solver result is:

[image]

Comment: Key notes: the `48000` *includes* April, and the `165K` goal is just for the months of May to December, not the whole year - that's the only way I could get back to the numbers in the question.

Comment: @BigBen  fixed in **EDIT#1** ....................................................

Comment: OH - sorry if my comment was unclear... the 165k goal means that the amounts for May to December should sum to 165k... the total year goal is 213k

Comment: @BigBen  ran Solver a third time and got ***1.11060178746152***

Comment: Yup... as it should be. I was trying to figure out if you could solve this formulaically without using Solver... but my math is rusty (*smacks forehead for not having done more of it in school*).

Comment: @BigBen  You can, indeed, use one of the Financial formulas, but I never do it that way................most of the time, people want to see all the monthly incremental values anyway

Comment: Which one... because the stream of payments isn't constant.